# Is it possible to create and use a Deferred object directly with AJAX?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, promise, jquery-deferred

I have an application which sends a few AJAX requests when a user clicks a specific button.

However, I also have something similar to a 'Cancel' button, which should abort all requests.

I'm using `$.when` currently to handle all of the requests sent, with appropriate callbacks added onto the `Promise` object it returns.

However, the fact that `$.when` returns a `Promise` object is frustrating, as it doesn't (deliberately) include the methods `Deferred` has to control the requests, as shown with this code:

Using $.when

```
var x = $.when($.get('/'), $.get('/')); // .then(function() {console.log('done');});

Object.keys(x); 
// ["state", "always", "then", "promise", "pipe", "done", "fail", "progress"]
```

Using one AJAX request (jqXHR implements the Deferred interface)

```
var x = $.get('/');

Object.keys(x); 
// ["readyState", "getResponseHeader", "getAllResponseHeaders", "setRequestHeader", "overrideMimeType", "statusCode", "abort", "state", "always", "then", "promise", "pipe", "done", "fail", "progress", "complete", "success", "error"]
```

I'm looking for a way to retrieve the `Deferred` object, or replace `$.when` with a method which performs the same, but returns a `Deferred` object instead. From there, I will be able to call a suitable reject / abort method.

Is this possible?

Comment: Cancellation is not on the Promise/Deferred interface, that's an ajax-only method and needs to be handled manually. Please also notice that jqXHR does not implement the Deferred interface (it doesn't have `reject`/`resolve` methods), but the Promise interface.

Comment: You could push your requests in an array like here: http://jsfiddle.net/Q3BV9/ Aborting request will reject the deferred object

Comment: @Bergi I see, thanks for pointing that out!
@A.Wolff That was a possibility I considered. The way it works with other requests, is that it stores the currently active (single) request, and calls `.abort` if a request is made before that one resolves. I think I need a good think about how to build this up, thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the requests into an array and abort them individually when you need to.

For this you can use `.apply` on `$.when`. For example:

```
var requests = [$.get('/'), $.get('/')];
$.when.apply($,requests).then(function(res1,res2){
      //access results here
});

// aborting:
requests.forEach(function(x){ return x.abort();});
```

Deferred objects are only used to create promises from callback APIs. You can not 'retrieve' the deferred object of an already existing promise. Only create new ones using it.

You might also want to look into Domenic's [`last()`](https://github.com/domenic/last).

Comment: Oh, I didn't see A. Wolff already suggested a similar solution. Props to him for suggesting it first, here is his fiddle with an example http://jsfiddle.net/Q3BV9/ .

Comment: Just for the sake of clarity, I've implemented a similar solution. Anyone reading this in future should know that aborting one request within the promise object **will fire off rejection triggers in the top promise object**. This is because deferred objects must have all of their conditions successfully resolved to be considered a success. If any 1 condition fails, it will instantly be considered a rejection. (This does not abort other conditions from running, however)